# Are Blood Oranges actually that red

Tags: fruit

I have tried 2 different brands of Taroccan blood orange and I have also had some Moro ones but none of them are that red like you see in pictures. Do I need to let them ripen or is it just hard to get ones that red?[image]

The ones I have had have a reddish tinge but still look like a normal orange. Thanks

Comment: Am not an expert on ripeness, etc. of blood oranges, but FWIW, whenever I have bought blood oranges (maybe 3 or 4 times) they have looked just like that picture... So dark they are almost purple, so the picture is likely "for real", not touched up or artfully colored or......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a blood orange be half bloody?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55694/can-a-blood-orange-be-half-bloody)

Comment: Yes, yes they are.  One of the Italian markets in Annapolis sells Sicilian blood orange juice which is very red.  I've also seen them occasionally in the Giant near me, and they've also been dark red.

Comment: @Stephie If I understand right, this is about the strength of the red color, not the uniformity.

Comment: @Jefromi both. The temperature gradient causes the fruit to develop the darker tones, from streaks to uniform redness. Colour distribution within the fruit can be very uneven also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is they can vary in redness. That would depend on the conditions they were grown in and the particular sort. Generally blood oranges are a deep (blood) red and lack the yellow tint of the other oranges. Your experience sounds perfectly normal. 
Hope this helps :)